# Rasterio version of ArcGIS raster pyramids

Tags: python, raster, arcgis, gdal, rasterio

In ArcGIS, when you load a Raster, you are offered the option to build pyramids. Like so:

[image]

I have found that I can replicate these files using the following Python code and the Rasterio library:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import Resampling

with rasterio.Env(TIFF_USE_OVR=True):

    with rasterio.open('new_new.tif', "w", **meta_data) as dest:
        dest.write(raster_data)
        overviews = [2,4,8,10,14,16]
        dest.build_overviews(overviews, Resampling.nearest)
```

However what I would like guidance on if possible, is how many 'overviews' in my code above will replicate the pyramids tool that ArcGIS runs? I'd like to try and create an identical output if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the original pyramid levels using the code in [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/overviews.html).

```
src = rasterio.open(path, 'r')
[src.overviews(i) for i in src.indexes]
src.tags(ns='rio_overview').get('resampling')
```

Arcmap uses view levels (2,4,8,16).
As far as I know, it's not possible to write overview files with compression using rasterio, so that you can't mimic the ovr's that are created by ESRI with compression.